# Why cannot set background to match_parent?

Tags: android, layout

I want to set background to match their parent like this image.

[image]

But it cannot and appears as below.

[image]

Layout code is here:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/stepbar_bg">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/M01_01"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="@drawable/step_1_bg"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change  android:layout_height="wrap_content"   .. To android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: Post the whole xml file

Comment: @Suhas B : i change it already but it the same.

Comment: I don´t complely understand Your problem, could You be more clear? So image 1 is what You want, image 2 what You get. Is Your problem that the grayed out numbers are not visible but should be?

Comment: ;post your complete xml file.

Comment: Yes i want like image 1.

Comment: @HuoChhunleng is there any margin/padding to outer layout ?

Comment: Share the code of your drawable xml used as background for both layouts. i.e. stepbar_bg and step_1_bg

Comment: is this a shape drawable or a real image as file?

Comment: i don't know why? now i open it again it's alright.
thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```